# Best data structuring practice for Note App Firestore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a note app that when the user is on the note screen, it should have a structure like this:

```
Title
   -Subtitle
        -Body Text
   -Subtitle
        -Body Text
```

and so on and so forth. Each of these Title,Subtitle, and Body Texts are stored in a POJO called NoteLine. Right now, in my firestore database my Notes are stored like this:

```
(Collection) Notes
        -(Doc) User ID
            -(Collection) Own Notes
              -(Doc) Note Name
                -(Collection) Here is where I want to store my NoteLines.
```

The way I am displaying these Note Lines are through a FirestoreRecyclerView. However, when the user adds a new line of body text in the note, since the new note line is sometimes going to be above previously created NoteLines and because I cannot specifically add NoteLines in my desired position within the collection, I don't know how to ensure that my RecyclerView will display the newly created body text in the correct position. I was thinking of having an ID system (where the first noteLine will have ID 1,the second 2, etc.) and query the collection in ID ascending order, but updating each NoteLine's ID everytime the user adds or deletes a NoteLine will take too long. If you need any extra information about my code, please ask and I will provide. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the ID (to 1,2,etc), I would suggest adding `creationDate` and `updationDate` fields in your Firebase for every note that you create. Then fetch the notes in descending order of your `updationDate`.

Note: Make sure you use the appropriate object for storing the date to Firestore and not use `String`. You won't be able to get the sorted results if you store them as a `String`

Comment: How would this help? For example, a user could create a body text in a subtitle that is higher than another body text in another subtitle that is lower down in the notes. According to your solution, wouldn’t the new body text be displayed lower than the older one when it should be higher?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to use descending order for this. Updated the answer.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think you understand my question. I'm asking for how to identify a noteline relative to its position among the other notelines in the note and display it in that order in the recyclerview, but it seems like you're giving me a way to sort the notelines depending on when they were last updated.